# Executing multiple URLs without redirection - JSP App

Tags: java, jsp, http, tomcat, sms

I'm working on JSP/Servlets Application deployed in Tomcat Server that sends sms via a sms api.
To send a sms I have to execute an URL like this one :

http://api.smsprovider.com/http/sendmsg?user=[USERNAME]&password=[PASSWORD]&api_id=XXXXX&to=123456789&text=Message

But I have to send multiple sms messages to numbers stored in a database.
So, The problem is how I can execute multiple URL in order to send these sms messages.

Please let me know if you have any idea :)

Best Regards.

Comment: You have to send one after another, as multiple requests. Btw: don't send password as GET and via http.

Comment: Just to add my two cents to @Stefan, you can use e.g. [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) library to execute the HTTP requests server-side (i.e. in a servlet).

Comment: Yes, I mean he should always go for https.

Comment: Many Thanks to stefan & Jozef ! I think the Apache HttpClient will be the adequate solution for my problem. please can you show me some examples how to use this library. THANK YOU